# Swift - TabBarController -> ViewController -> NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

i have the following situation:

I got a TabBarController with some tabs(ViewControllers).

When i am in one of these ViewControllers, i tap a button and i want to segue to a NavigationController AND still see the tabbar...

Here is what i did:

1. I created a new ViewController(DetailViewController)
2. I embedded this new ViewController(DetailViewController) in a NavigationController
3. I created a segue(Show) from the "viewcontroller which is embedded in the tabbarcontroller" to the "new navigationcontroller"
4. I coded:

   ```
   func buttonTapped {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "shownavicontroller", sender: nil
   }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
       let destinationNavigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
       let targetController = destinationNavigationController.topViewController as! DetailViewController
   }
   ```

What goes wrong:

1. NavigationController is sliding from bottom to top... it should slide from left to right
2. BackButton in NavigationController is missing
3. TabBar in NavigationController is missing...

Anybody could help me with this issue?

Thanks and Greetings!!

Comment: Have you tried the following setup: `Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller -> "viewcontroller which is embedded in the tabbarcontroller" -> Detail View Controller`? That's how you typically use a `UINavigationController`...

Answer (score 0):

You have done wrong.
You should not embed UIViewController directly to tabBarController to get the desired result you want.

**From Storybaord,**

If you are designing your application from storyboard then you should add a `UIViewController` and embed this `UIViewController` object into `UINavigationController` and then embed this `NavigationController` in a `UITabBarController`. So that if a button in above `UIViewController` is pressed and you need to open an other `UIViewController` not form Bottom to Top but from Left to Right and expecting a Automatic back button at top bar and hide bottom bar.
Then you need to create a Push/Show Segue form Above `ViewController` (Embed in `NavigationController` -> Embed in `TabBarController`) to you new UIViewController that will open.
And before calling the push/show segue you need to write bellow lines.

```
self.tabBarController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, i corrected my architecture: Tabbar -> ViewController(embedded in NavigationBar) -> ViewController... , but no i get error, Receiver "TabBarController" has no segue with identifier "shownavicontroller", why?

Comment: Select the Segue that is from your DetailViewController to NextViewController from Storyboard. After selection in right panel you will see properties of your segue just sent the identifier to "shownavicontroller".
For Visual Appearance infomation Check @Kegham Answer

Answer (score -1):

According to your question i believe this is what you need:

[image]

[image]