# Presenting View Controller within Navigation Controller and TabbarController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Coming from a separate IntroViewController, I'm trying to present a UIViewController that's embedded in a UINavigationController, which is also one of three option in a UITabbarController.

```
let tabVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController")
self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabVC!), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I present my View Controller with the code above, the Navigation controller isn't complete, missing the bar items from all the View Controllers (see image).

[image]

I've been on this for a few hours, and can either only get the TabbarController to show, the UINavigationController, but not both.
Thanks for any help. Much appreciated!

UPDATE: I should clarify, the problem only exists when I try to present it from another View Controller. When I use it as an initial View Controller, everything is fine.

Comment: Check this maybe it would help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122404/swift-tabbarcontroller-viewcontroller-navigationcontroller/44122801#44122801

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to init your viewControllers in tabBar controller class.
I use different storyboard for  every viewController and tabBarButton but you also can init them from one storyboard just init right view controller in makeTabBarItemForViewController method

```
private func loadViewControllers(animated: Bool){

    var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()
    viewControllers.append(self.makeTabBarItemForViewController(storyboardIdentifier: "CurrentChannels", title: LocalizationUtil.localizedString(forKey: "On Air"), selectedImageName: Assets.tabBarIconOnAir.rawValue, imageName: Assets.tabBarIconOnAirUnselected.rawValue))
    self.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: animated)
}


private func makeTabBarItemForViewController(storyboardIdentifier: String,title:String , selectedImageName:String , imageName:String)-> UIViewController{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardIdentifier, bundle: nil)
    let vc:UIViewController? = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController();
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let notSelectedImage = UIImage(named:selectedImageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let item = UITabBarItem(title: title, image: selectedImage, selectedImage: notSelectedImage)
    vc!.tabBarItem = item

    if let navVC = vc as? UINavigationController{
        navVC.delegate = self
    }
    return vc!
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. This is great! I ended up reworking the UX so that what used to be the original presenter is now being presented conditionally.